# Python using values, while reading line by line

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
Name    Date of Birth   Favourite fruit
John    06.07.1989      Apple
Tim     12.03.1999      Kiwi
Kelly   ...             ... 
Borris  ...             ...
...     ...             ...
```

I'm looking to print out all of my table (infinite, got a script that adds to it), It should look something like this (doesn't nessercerly have to look like this, just as example):

```
OUTPUT:
(John(born: 06.07.1989, fruit: Apple)), (Tim(born: 12.03.1999, fruit: Kiwi))
```

How can I loop this proccess, of taking value by value and printing it out? I've never worked pandas before. I'm lost at this point.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is your table in a .csv file or have you already read it into a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are trying to do. What is your "table"? Is this some text file on your disk? How would `pandas` be involved here?

Comment: If your file is in principle infinite then don't use `pandas` because `pandas` will attempt to read all into memory. If it is a .csv then use the `csv` module. If it is something else you need to present a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use `.format` function with `**` to get cells without other symbols.

In `'...'.format(..)` you can insert column names this way `{Name}`.
Try this:

```
 import pandas as pd     

 df=pd.read_excel("yourfile.xlsx")
 nlist=['({Name}(born: {Date of Birth}, fruit: {Favourite fruit})),'.format(**df.iloc[x]) for x in df.index]    
 print(*nlist)
```

[image]